# Rails Circular Dependency Errors in rake task only when multithreading without delete_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I am trying to create a rake task to do some updating of data. the problem is it is kind of slow so i thought i would make it multi threaded to speed it up. the problem is when i run it in 1 thread its fine but when i run it in 5 threads i only sometimes get

```
rake aborted!
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ClassInfo
/home/Tomer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/Tomer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/home/Tomer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/Tomer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/home/Tomer/workspace/DrexelRegistrationBackend/app/helpers/html_parse_helper.rb:66:in `block in load_class_from_link'
/home/Tomer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'
/home/Tomer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
/home/Tomer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'
/home/Tomer/workspace/DrexelRegistrationBackend/app/helpers/html_parse_helper.rb:59:in `load_class_from_link'
/home/Tomer/workspace/DrexelRegistrationBackend/app/helpers/html_parse_helper.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in load_classes_from_catalog'
/home/Tomer/workspace/DrexelRegistrationBackend/app/helpers/html_parse_helper.rb:42:in `each'
/home/Tomer/workspace/DrexelRegistrationBackend/app/helpers/html_parse_helper.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in load_classes_from_catalog'
```

I am using nokogiri and opening a url and html parsing it and then inserting it into my database. The weird thing is if i insert ClassInfo.delete_all in the beginning the error goes away, but i dont want to do that. I need to check if its in my database so i check if it exists in this line which is where i crashes

```
myclass = ClassInfo.find_by(class_id: class_id)
```

It has no joins or other classes dependent on it this is my migrate

```
create_table :class_infos do |t|
      t.text :class_id, index: true
      t.text :subject_code
      t.text :subject
      t.text :course_number
      t.text :title
      t.float :credits_lower_range
      t.float :credits_upper_range
      t.text :description
      t.boolean :writing_intensive
      t.text :college
      t.text :repeat_status
      t.text :prereqs
      t.text :restrictions
      t.text :coreqs
      t.text :term_type
      t.text :student_type
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

and this is the model

```
class ClassInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

the very weird thing is that after it crashes i can usually run the rake task again immediately and it works fine the second time. Very weird

Here is mostly my entire module called from my rake

```
require 'open-uri'

module HtmlParseHelper

def self.parse_catalog
    Thread.abort_on_exception=true
    @@threads = Array.new
       load_classes_from_catalog(url_sections)  #an array of 5 arrays contaning urls objects
    @@threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
end


def self.load_classes_from_catalog(urlArr)
    arrs.each{|urlSection|
      @@threads.push(
           Thread.new do
             urlSection.each{|url|                     
load_class_from_link(url[0],url[1],url[2],url[3])
                 }
                 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
               end
          )
        }
  end


def self.load_class_from_link(link, term_type, student_type, subject)

    begin
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))do |config|
      config.strict.noblanks
    end
    class_id = doc.css('div.courseblock').children[0].text
    drexel_class = ClassInfo.find_by(class_id: class_id)   #where it crashes
    #.....
    drexel_class.save
end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/112077c255879351edf4530791cc4bcc7bd4005b

int the end it was eager loading that was screwing me up.

i just added

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

to the beginning and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Eager loading did not, unfortunately, help me with this. I 'solved' it by referencing the dependencies first in a rake task that is serially executed before running the multitask:

```
   task do_stuff: [:environment] do 
      b = MyModelThatTriggersCircularDependencies
      b = MyOtherModelThatAlsoMisbehaves
      Rake::Task['my_multitask'].invoke
   end

   multitask my_multitask: CONVERT_TXT_TO_MD
```